# Looking for some sort of pattern

Tags: java, android

I have a library project which contains an abstract class, let's say `ClassA`. In the project that uses that library project, I have `ClassB` that extends `ClassA`.

Now here's my problem. In the library project I want to use an instance of the implemented `ClassB`, but I have no idea how to retrieve that instance. Is there any pattern or other ideas for this?

[Here's](http://s3.amazonaws.com/twitpic/photos/full/326584019.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJF3XCCKACR3QDMOA&Expires=1308603198&Signature=N4yDX66sr7fDCGDaHXmY/MXBcmY=) a simple diagram of the situation.

**Edit**

The reason I'm asking is that I'm creating multiple applications, which only have different methods in `ClassB`. Therefore I'm creating a library that all of these applications can use, only having to extend `ClassA`. These applications are separate projects, using the library.

Comment: I don't have direct access to ClassB, as it is in an other project.

Comment: An intereseting problem as you'll effectively create a circular reference.  Forgive the dumb question, but if you are able to apparently get to the source code for the Library (by the nature you want to use ClassB from the library versus from the extending application) what's stopping you from doing that?  I know that doesn't answer your question directly, but unless there's a way to "inject" into the library I don't think you can do specificially what you want.

Comment: @CirrusFlyer: Most of the answers are assuming that the library's references to ClassB need to be hard-coded. But if a factory pattern is used, the library can **use** ClassB without **knowing about** ClassB. See my answer, below.

Comment: @Dan:  Yes, agreed.  What's implied is the fact that Niek can modify and has acess to the source code for the library containing Class A.  Based on his original posting (and not having any similar mechanisms as you've suggested, or access to the source) there is no way for Niek to achieve what he wanted.  But, if he does have access to the source then that changes everything ... the fact that, based on his edited statement about wanting to use this with many applications, your suggestion is a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is something like the [Abstract Factory](http://www.allapplabs.com/java_design_patterns/abstract_factory_pattern.htm) pattern. The application code (the code that calls into the library) would, at some point, need to pass in a Factory class that would be used by the library to create instances of ClassA objects. In your case, the Factory class would generate instances of ClassB.

Depending on the design and functionality of the classes, it's likely that ClassA should be redesigned as an interface, or at least as an abstract class, as part of this refactoring.

**EDIT**:
Here's an untested pseudo example:

**This code would be in the library**

```
class INeedAFactory {
    public Interface MyFactory {
        public ClassA makeClassAInstance();
    }

    private MyFactory m_factory;
    public registerFactory(MyFactory factory) {
        m_factory = factory;
    }

    private ClassA makeClassAInstance() {
        // m_factory had better not be null!
        return m_factory.makeClassAInstance();
    }

    private void ClassAConsumer() {
        ClassA classA = makeClassAInstance();
        // ... etc. ...
    }
}
```

**This code would be in the application:**

```
class LibraryPatron {
    class MakeClassB implements INeedAFactory.MyFactory {
        public ClassA makeClassAInstance() {
            return new ClassB();
        }
    }
    public LibraryPatron() {
        INeedAFactory libraryObject = new INeedAFactory();
        libraryObject.registerFactory(new MakeClassB());
        // ... etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is steering me in the right direction. I can create an abstract method `public abstract ClassA getClass();` in my library and let the other project implement that as `public abstract ClassA getClass(){ return new ClassB();}`

Comment: Thanks, this is helping me a lot.

Comment: @Niek: Yes, that could work. The only catch is that you need a place to put getClass. Obviously, you can't put it in either ClassA or in ClassB, because the library doesn't know how to find ClassB. That's why my example shows a separate object thats created in the application code and passed into the libary. That object (which would implement `getClass()`, in your example) effectively gives the library the ability to create ClassB objects.

Answer (score 1):

If your library needs to use ClassB, then ClassB should be part of your library.  Your library shouldn't need to know about classes in projects which use it.

If your library just needs a ClassA, and you've got a ClassB, you can cast your object to a ClassA before you pass it in, like this:

```
ClassB b = new ClassB();
ClassA a = (ClassA)b;
// pass a into your library
```

Answer (score 0):

Move class B into the same library as class A. Your project already depends on the library so it will still be able to reference class B but class B will also now be available to other classes within the library.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really clear, but as I understand it if you want to get an instance of the `ClassB` you just need to do a `new ClassB()`...

Answer (score 0):

So you're writing an abstract class and you want it to be able to get a hold of all objects of unknown sub-classes of that class? It sounds to me like you're wanting an Aspect-Oriented management like [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) or [PicoContainer](http://picocontainer.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I feel sick when I write this, because your design is flawed, but you asked how you would do it....so here it goes:

```
Class<?> bClass = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("com.foo.ClassB");
```

Then you can do something like:

```
if (object.getClass() == bClass) { ... }
```

I would seriously recommend coming up with a better solution however.  Try writing your code in one project then re-factor out common things that can make up your "library".

Comment: I know it's kind of ugly, but the one or two methods in that class are the only things that make the difference between app 1 and app 2. Designing it this way seemed the most simple way.. Well, seemed ^.^